# When filtering query on custom taxonomy; main menu dissapears

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, menus

I have created a custom taxonomy, and that works.

But here is the problem;
I have created an archive page, which in the url gets e.g. this: `?category=23`. Then, in `functions.php`, I do this:

```
function add_inspiration_category( $q ) {
    if (is_post_type_archive('inspiration') && !is_admin()) {

        $category_id = $_GET['category'];
        if (!empty($category_id)) {
            $q->set('tax_query', array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'inspiration-taxonomy',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $category_id
                )
            ));
        }
    }

    return $q;
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'add_inspiration_category');
```

So, basically I'm filtering the archive pages result based on the id in the url. This works, except when I'm filtering on a category, the main menu dissapears from the header. If I remove the `?category=23` from the url or comment out the section above where I set the `tax_query`, it works as expected again. Anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying that filter to every query on the pages matching the conditions or that `if`. You need to restrict this to only the main query and make sure that the conditions are only operating on the `$q` query passed into the function.

```
if ($q->is_main_query() 
   && $q->is_post_type_archive('inspiration') 
   && !is_admin()) {
```